# Custom ordering MSSQL hibernate Spring boot 2

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a select query via specifications that queries the result of a list that **most of the time** starts with Q. For example:

```
Q2
Q19
Q120
arandomstring
Q3
```

I want to sort the list following these rules:

Ascending:

```
Q2
Q3
Q19
Q120
arandomstring
```

Descending:

```
arandomstring
Q120
Q19
Q3
Q2
```

Note that the first letter is stripped away from the field and that the numbers are interpreted as integers. Not as text.

I was wondering if this is possible with the hibernate specification API and MSSQL? I found out that there is already something like a custom sort order in MSSQL (https://sqlandme.com/2013/11/18/sql-server-custom-sorting-in-order-by-clause/) but in the hibernate documentation I did not found anything so far.

Is it possible to implement this on database level and not application level?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a raw SQL Server query which would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN col LIKE 'Q%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN col LIKE 'Q%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 2, LEN(col)) AS INT) ELSE 0 END;
```

### Demo

In terms of getting this query to work in Hibernate, most of it would map without any issues, except that perhaps `SUBSTRING` cannot be used in the `ORDER BY` clause.  To workaround, you might have to subquery first, and then order.

Comment: Doesn't look like this will work correctly for `arandomstring` for the second order by criteria

Comment: @MartinSmith Um...there is no "second" order by criteria, as a single query only has a single `ORDER BY` clause.  The OP should retain two different queries in its Java code if he has two sorting requirements.

Comment: The second column in the order by list. i.e. the secondary criteria if the primary one is tied

Comment: It's probably worth adding `Col` at the end of the `ORDER BY` here. If the OP has multiple rows that didn't start with `'Q'` the order of the rows would be complete arbitrary for them. It's a guess that they should be in alphabetical order, but I *assume* they do want them ordered.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your answer, this takes me one step further already. I optimized your query btw by using the sql server functions to replace the case. `SELECT x
FROM table
ORDER BY IIF(x LIKE 'K%', 0, 1) ASC,
         IIF(x LIKE 'K%', CAST(SUBSTRING(x, 2, LEN(x)) AS INT), 0) ASC;`

Next step is getting it into hibernate with specifications

Comment: @VinceV. To clarify a bunch of doubts here, are you looking to write an _HQL_ Hibernate query, or do you want to write a native SQL Server query, or, are you open to both options?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not looking for HQL, I am using the specifications API from hibernate (example: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/specifications.html) So my job now is to wrap it in that api. :) Happy birthday btw!

Comment: @VinceV. Spring Data in fact uses Hibernate under the hood, so my question still stands.  Do you want a native query, or do you want to use HQL/JPA?

Comment: I want a JPA one, but I did not know how to write it natively, now I at least have a starting point already. That is the +1 vote for :). My next job is how to wrap it so it can dynamically change with the rest of my filters

Answer (score 2):

This is less than ideal; if you have values that should be treated as numerical data you should be storing it as a numerical value.

Anyway, you can use `STUFF` to remove the first character, and `TRY_CONVERT` the value with a numerical data type:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(YourColumn,1,1,'')) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(YourColumn,1,1,'')),
         YourColumn;
```

ideally if you need to store numerical data and (more importantly) *treat* it as numerical data you should be using a numerical data type. Here it seems that  the numbers for values prefixed with `'Q'` should be stored in a separate `int` column to the column that has `'arandomstring'`, without the `'Q'` prefix. This would mean that the problem would be far more trivial, as it would simply be `ORDER BY OriginalColumn, Question` (assuming `'Q'` means question).

Comment: This is a Hibernate question.  There is no `STUFF` function available, unless the OP decides to use a native query (which is perfectly possible, but then would tie down the application code to SQL Server in particular).

Comment: True, but considering the OP has tagged a specific RDBMS, I've taken the assumption they are have done that, @TimBiegeleisen .

Comment: `I was wondering if this is possible with the hibernate API and MSSQL?`

Comment: Maybe I'm picking on you for no good reason, but on the Java side of things, applications which use _Hibernate_ are _not_ writing native SQL, they're writing HQL, and using `STUFF` would only be possible from a native query, which the OP might now want to do.

Comment: That's fair, @TimBiegeleisen . If that is what the OP is after, I'll certainly remove this. They haven't defined that in the question, so this does at least give them a solution. If that is a caveat of the answer required it should likely be defined by the OP. (Though my point on storing numerical data in a numerical data type stands! :) )

Comment: Happy Birthday, @TimBiegeleisen . Hope you enjoy the day.